# how to maintain session in cURL in php?

Tags: php, curl

how can we maintain session in cURL?

i'am having a code the sends login details of a site and logs in successfully
i need to get the session maintained at the site to continue.

here is my code that used to login to the site using cURL

```
  <?php  
        $socket = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.XXXXXXX.com");
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.XXXXXXX.com");
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "form_logusername=XXXXX&form_logpassword=XXXXX");
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    $data = curl_exec($socket);
    curl_close($socket); 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is the best way i found to do this [link](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/) :

the text bellow is a 'remixed' version of the content of the [blogpost](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/) :

```
 $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';

session_write_close();

$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($rssFeedLink); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

What does `session_write_close()` do? It, ends the current session and store session data. Apparently, PHP does not like when multiple scripts play around with the session, so, it locks it. Putting session_write_close makes sure that your current session is stored so you can retrieve it and use it.

if you don't use `session_write_close()` a new session id will be generated instead of using the current session id.

Also **PHPSESSID** should be replaced by the name of the session variable. According to [OWSAP recommandations](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_management) it should be something more general like **anId**.

Sometimes you will need to send a user agent with the post so i included the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` parameter.

Comment: I've been looking for this for the past 2 hours or so. I'm building an API and in there I'm requesting a different API and while it seemed to work, the curl connection was timing out before executing anything. The only thing missing was `session_write_close();` Thanks!

Comment: tahnks works fine

Answer (score 16):

This is how you do CURL with sessions

```
//initial request with login data

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/profile');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

I've seen this on ImpressPages

Comment: This is a standalone snippet that actually works. For me, the best answer.

Comment: Note that this never calls `curl_close($ch)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're referring to a cookies.txt file without any reference to a folder my first guess would be that you're trying to write to a file in a folder that isn't writable. So first check if you actually find a cookies.txt file and if it contains the session cookie(s) you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay
the folder contains cookies.txt file and it is writble with permissions 777

Comment: Is it empty? Curl treats session cookies as non-expiring. If not, try truncating it first. Also you should set the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to make sure you complete the login

Answer (score 0):

I would probably move that code into a function. After successful login, you now have the session associated with the cookie you have in your cookie.txt file. On subsequent requests, just keep using that cookie file and you should have a valid session on that site.