# Multiple Requests with cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl

I am currently trying to scrape this website using cURL in PHP.

http://wateroffice.ec.gc.ca/report/report_e.html?mode=Table&type=realTime&stn=02HD006&dataType=&startDate=2014-09-22&endDate=2014-09-29&prm1=46&prm2=-1

There seems to be a confirmation page that needs to hit before actually viewing the data.  On the confirmation page there is a form that gets posted to /includes/disclaimer.php with a post variable of

dislcaimer_action=I Agree

I've tried the following code but the second request seems to always bring me back to the confirmation page.

```
 $browser = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_URL, "http://wateroffice.ec.gc.ca/include/disclaimer.php");
 curl_setopt($browser ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);  

 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

 $postData = 'disclaimer_action=I Agree';

 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

 curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_URL, "http://wateroffice.ec.gc.ca/report/report_e.html?mode=Table&type=realTime&stn=02HD006&dataType=&startDate=2014-09-22&endDate=2014-09-29&prm1=46&prm2=-1");
 $output = curl_exec($browser);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass POSTFIELDS as an associative array, just like using `$_POST['disclaimer_action']`, but not, in a way.

```
$postData = array('disclaimer_action' => 'I Agree');
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

- [The documentation](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt)

Comment: Thanks for the fix, the example I was going off of was using a scalar variable for the post data.  However this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm. When you do it manually in your browser, after clicking `I agree`, do you have a session set?

Comment: Interesting idea,

Looks like there are 4 cookies being set which includes a PHPSESSION cookie and a disclaimer cookie.

Comment: Okay, this is why you cannot get to the next page. Perhaps give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15374966/3000179) a whirl.