# POST request with session id gets stuck without error

Tags: php, api, session, curl

I'm trying to create a simple to use API with php but I have run into multiple problems. I'm working on an user api that does basic CRUD stuff.

If I do a POST request with cURL to my user api (user.php), a new session id is used during the execution of user.php.

So in order to combat that I tried to send the current session id with the POST request to user.php. The problem I have right now is that after setting the id with `session_id($_POST['session'])` and then starting my session with `session_start()` my server will get stuck on executing that code and will eventually throw an Internal Server Error 500.

I tried to get my server to show me what the error is with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and an .htaccess file (content: `php_flag display_errors 1`) but to no avail, the server just gets stuck.

test.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Check for available session
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location: index.php');
    } else {
        // Initialize cURL
        $curl = curl_init();

        // Set parameters for POST request
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/api/user.php',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
                'session' => session_id(),
                'username' => 'testuser',
                'password' => 'testalot',
                'name' => 'testuser',
                'isAdmin' => 0
            ])
        ]);

        // Execute POST request
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        /* <<< Doesn't get beyond this point. */

        // Dump JSON
        var_dump($response);

        // Close cURL session
        curl_close($curl);
    }
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
  // Declare integer checking function
  function isInteger($input) {
    return ctype_digit(strval($input));
  }

  // Declare result object
  $output = ['success' => false, 'data' => [], 'error' => ''];

  // Action on POST
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Check if session id was sent
    if (!empty($_POST['session'])) {
      // Set session id
      session_id($_POST['session']);

      // Start session with received session id
      session_start();

      /* <<< Freezes at this point. */

      // Check session for available user id
      if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        // Only admins are allowed to execute POST requests
        if ($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == 1) {
          // ... more code ...
```

I'd of course also use a different method of accessing my API that does not require me to send the current session id, if there is any. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Look @Neok's comment under my question. That is the solution. Just pointing it out for others that might have the same issue.

Comment: Add this code line at the start of your page for error reporting. it might help. error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Look at this question - [how to maintain php sessions with curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424714/how-to-maintain-session-in-curl-in-php)

Comment: and can you try sending $_SESSION['id'] instead of session_id()? And comment out session_start(); at user php?

Comment: @Neok I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: First you have to check echo session_id(). Its returning something ?.

Comment: @Atilla I'm setting $_SESSION['id'] to the user id of my database... is that bad?

Comment: @Monty Yes the correct session id that is used at the moment. Login & logout works on my page.

Comment: @HitomiTenshi So $_SESSION['id'] worked? Now if you need to use it in a query you might want to sanitize it.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz No, $_SESSION['id'] does not hold the value of the current session id. It instead holds the id of the currently logged in user on my page.

Comment: use $_SESSION['id'] instead of session_id(). If does not work than assign session_id() to variable and use that variable.

Comment: I don't know how i missed that but here is your problem. using 2 session at the same time. As documentation says "As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.". So that causes you to get 500 error. Just simply dont use it or destroy previous session before you start a new one

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz I think you didn't get what I was writing. Anyway, problem is solved now.

Comment: @Neok Thank you Neok! Your link was the solution! I had to execute `session_write_close();` before doing the POST request. Also I don't need to send the session id now. `CURLOPT_COOKIE` works wonders. Thank you again, you're the real MVP!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that php.ini is set to log all errrors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: I have no access to the php.ini on the server that I'm using :(
I tried to run everything locally with xampp but that also didn't help. No errors are thrown, the execution is just stuck... in an endless loop you could say.

Comment: so, do it in php with 'ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)'

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) says `session_id()` returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists). So instead of taking `$_SESSION['id']`, try that:

```
// Check for available session
if (session_id() == "") {
    header('location: index.php');
} else {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise your code redirects to index.php in a loop causing error 500.