# php - maintain session across curl requests

Tags: php, session, curl

I have been able to use my current session in the process created by my curl request using the following code -

```
$query = http_build_query(array(
   "pcode"=>strtolower($code)
));
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].":".PUBLIC_ROOT."xyz.php"."?".$query;

session_write_close();

$curl = curl_init($url);
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I used the following answer for the above code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15374966/815929

Now the issue is that in the new process (created by the curl request), I need to set some session variables. However these session variables do not reflect in the calling process after `curl_close()`.

I had some session vars in my calling script. I was able to use these session vars in the new process started by the curl request. This new process also set some new session vars. However when we are back to the calling process these new session vars are not reflected.

Are there additional curl options that I need to set to make this work?

Comment: *"Are there additional curl options that i need to set to make this work?"* -- have you read the documentation of [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)? All the options are explained there; the ones you need are `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` (you need to use both to persist the cookies across `curl_exec()` calls.)

Comment: _“However these session variables do not reflect in the calling process after curl_close()”_ - of course they don’t, because your calling process read the session data only once, when it was started. Plus, your cURL request should not even be able to _write_ new session data - the session file should still be locked, because your calling process is using the session, and therefor your cURL request should just “hang” ... you’d need to call session_write_close in your calling process first, before this should even work in theory ...

Comment: @CBroe session_write_close() is mentioned above. Im not clear with which cookie data does each of these store - CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. And that do i have to get data out of the file set in  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to use the data in the calling process.

Comment: @axiac i have done the following -  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . '/mirazmac_cookie.txt' ); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/mirazmac_cookie.txt' ); but session variables are not reflecting in calling process.

Comment: I thought by "session variables" you mean the session on the server you access using `curl`. For this purpose, you need to persist the cookies you get from the remote server. If you are talking about the session managed by your script, please ignore my previous comment. `curl` doesn't directly interact with the session of the script that uses the `curl_*` functions.

Comment: @axiac - Let me explain more clearly.  I had some session vars in my calling script. I was able to use these session vars in the new process started by the curl request. This new process also set some *new* session vars. However when we are back to the calling process these new session vars are not reflected.

Comment: Let me see if I understood: you use `curl_exec()` to send a request to a script on your server and expect the changes operated in the session by the requested script to be instantly available in the script that uses `curl_exec()`?

Comment: yes @axiac, also there is no remote server here. I am hitting the original server again and again using curl.

Comment: It doesn't work this way. It *could* work if you call [`session_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php) followed by [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) right after `curl_exec()` but it might fail as well (now or in the future).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159160/discussion-between-rnjai-and-axiac).

Comment: @axiac calling session_abort() followed by session_start() worked. Is this a good practice? I dont think so as the client which was calling will get the response.

Comment: _“Is this a good practice?”_ - I’d say you already left the path of good practice way before that, with this weird "cURL request updates session" mechanism ...

Comment: @CBroe agree with your view..

Comment: Final take by @axiac -  You should definitely refactor your code and run everything in a single script unless you have strong reasons to invoke the other script using HTTP. Such a reason usually is the isolation provided by a separate request and the isolation is exactly what you want to break here. Another reason to not use HTTP to run the other script is the speed and server load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to imagine how this runs at all.

> However these session variables do not reflect in the calling process after curl_close()

Using the default session handler, a second script should just timeout if it is called from something like....

```
session_start();
...
curl_exec(); // at this point session file is still locked
...
[session_close();]
```

> $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';

eh? You don't specify a path for a cookie in an HTTP request (you do in a response). This will tell the script that the client has a cookie named "path".

Really this should be....

$strCookie = session_name() . "=" . session_id();

> However these session variables do not reflect in the calling process after curl_close()

Did you reload the session from storage? (see also previous note about session file locking). Your code should do something like....

```
session_start();
...
session_close();
...
curl_exec();
...
session_start();
```

it would be cleaner to switch to a [non-blocking handler](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/faster-and-more-scalable-session.html), or better yet don't pass state via the session - POST the data to the second script read the response from the output stream.