# PHP, trying to curl download csv from website that needs a session

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download public german short positions as a CSV, but I am coming up short.

[Website address](https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?global_data.language=en&page.navid=to_nlp_start&session.sessionid=&global_data.designmode=eb)

My dummycode is as follows:

1. Load first page and get the session.sessionid.
2. Use the id to follow the "More search options" link
3. Post a request into the "More search options"-page.
4. Receive the csv

Any tips here? I guess I have problems with the cookie. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?global_data.language=en&page.navid=to_nlp_start&session.sessionid=&global_data.designmode=eb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');

echo '<br>--------------------------------------<br>';
echo substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);
$id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

echo '<br>';
echo '-----------------------------------------<br>';



$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?page.navid=nlpstarttonlpstart_new&nlp_search_param.extended_search=true&session.sessionid=' . $id;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);



$data = array(

   "session.sessionid:" => $id,
   "nlp_search_param.publisher:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.emittent:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.isin:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.search_history:" => "true",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:0:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:1:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:2:" => "2001",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:0:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:1:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:2:" => "2019",
   "nlp_search_param.position_start:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.position_end:" => "", 
   "(page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlist_updatefilter):" => "Show net short positions"
);


 $url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?session.sessionid=' . $id . '&page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlistdownloadcsv';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);


$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet';
 $postvars = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

 echo 'Result:<br>';

 var_dump($server_output);

 curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Update: I tried using the example Nigel linked to, but still I am not able to do it. However, the last link this next code creates ($url), when pasted into my browser (chrome) will sometimes work (csv downloads). However, it newer works with curl.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?global_data.language=en&page.navid=to_nlp_start&session.sessionid=&global_data.designmode=eb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts

$answer = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

$result = $answer;

//var_dump($result);

$trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');

echo '<br>-------------------1-------------------<br>';
echo substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);
$id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

echo '<br>';
echo '-----------------------1------------------<br>';


$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?page.navid=nlpstarttonlpstart_new&nlp_search_param.extended_search=true&session.sessionid=' . $id;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

$result = $answer;

//var_dump($result);

$trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');

echo '<br>----------------2----------------------<br>';
echo substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);
$id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

echo '<br>';
echo '-------------------2----------------------<br>';


$data = array(

   "session.sessionid:" => $id,
   "nlp_search_param.publisher:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.emittent:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.isin:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.search_history:" => "false",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:0:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:1:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_start:2:" => "2001",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:0:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:1:" => "1",
   "nlp_search_param.date_end:2:" => "2019",
   "nlp_search_param.position_start:" => "",
   "nlp_search_param.position_end:" => "", 
   "(page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlist_updatefilter):" => "Show net short positions"
);

var_dump($data);

$url = 'https://bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet/';
$postvars = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

$result = $answer;

//var_dump($result);

$trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');

echo '<br>----------------3----------------------<br>';
echo substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);
$id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

echo '<br>';
echo '-------------------3----------------------<br>';

$url = "https://bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?session.sessionid=" . $id . '&amp;page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlistdownloadcsv';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
echo '<br>';
echo '-------------------4----------------------<br>';
echo $url . '<br>';
var_dump($answer);

file_put_contents('test.csv', $answer);
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424714/how-to-maintain-session-in-curl-in-php help?

Comment: if nobody figures it out by 7 november, feel free to send me a reminder on facebook/email

Comment: Your code is running fine. I don't see any option to request a .csv on the website though. Is there such an option?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nigel. Unfortunatly I am not able to make it work.

Comment: David, yes there is such an option, but you need to get to page number three. 
First click "more search options" and then fill out the dates, and do a search. Then you will see a csv option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found some issues in your original code that, when fixed, will return the .csv you're looking for.

**1. The `sessionid` changes**

After your initial request with no `sessionid`, you store the resulting value and use it throughout. However when I test in the browser, this value changes after the POST. So you'll want a function to grab the sessionid from each request you make:

```
function get_sessionid($result)
{
  $trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');
  $id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

  return $id;
}
```

Be sure to update your `$id` value after each curl request.

**2. The server expects a GET request**

Your code requesting the .csv doesn't unset the POST request. Also, that .csv request is triggered before an actual search. Using a POST request will prevent the server from returning the .csv data.

I also tested things like setting the `CURLOPT_SSL_*` options, using cookie files and setting an `Accept:` header but it turns out none of those were to blame.

**3. Your POST keys are incorrect**

I am assuming that these have been copied from the Web Inspector. The POST keys shouldn't have a `:` after them; they are shown in the inspector for readability.

Your process would be:

1. Request the original URL
2. Get the `sessionid`
3. Make a POST request for search results
4. Update the `sessionid`
5. Make a GET request for the .csv

Edit: Full amended code below

```
<?php

function get_sessionid($result)
{
  $trueposition = strpos($result, 'session.sessionid=');
  $id = substr($result,$trueposition+18,32);

  return $id;
}

// First request for a sessionid
$ch = curl_init('https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?global_data.language=en&page.navid=to_nlp_start&session.sessionid=&global_data.designmode=eb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Remove this line if you don't want to see the headers:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Get the sessionid
$id = get_sessionid($result);

// Requesting the search page
$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?page.navid=nlpstarttonlpstart_new&nlp_search_param.extended_search=true&session.sessionid=' . $id;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Updating the sessionid
$id = get_sessionid($result);

// Build the search
$data = array(
  "session.sessionid" => $id,
  "nlp_search_param.publisher" => "",
  "nlp_search_param.emittent" => "",
  "nlp_search_param.isin" => "",
  "nlp_search_param.search_history" => "true",
  "nlp_search_param.date_start:0" => "1",
  "nlp_search_param.date_start:1" => "1",
  "nlp_search_param.date_start:2" => "2001",
  "nlp_search_param.date_end:0" => "1",
  "nlp_search_param.date_end:1" => "1",
  "nlp_search_param.date_end:2" => "2019",
  "nlp_search_param.position_start" => "",
  "nlp_search_param.position_end" => "",
  "(page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlist_updatefilter)" => "Show net short positions"
);

// Searching
$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet';
$postvars = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

// Updating the sessionid
$id = get_sessionid($result);

// Request the CSV
$url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?session.sessionid=' . $id . '&page.navid=nlpresultlisttonlpresultlistdownloadcsv';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Reset to a GET request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Super David! Thank you so much! This helps a lot, now I can download active positions. :) There is still one more issue though: Setting "nlp_search_param.search_history:" to "true" gives the same same result. As does changing the dates. So the get request for the variables does not seem to work properly for some reason. Any ideas why? I need to download active and historical positions.

Comment: @Maggem Whoops, I didn't spot that your POST keys had colons added. Once they are removed, the variables work as expected. Updated my answer.

Comment: Fantastic @David, that solves it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maggern Great! Glad you can move forward with your project. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted?