# Get info from API/URL

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents

I have the URL https://android.rediptv2.com/ch.php?usercode=5266113827&pid=1&mac=02:00:00:00:00:00&sn=&customer=GOOGLE&lang=eng&cs=amlogic&check=3177926680
which outputs statistics.

For example:

```
[{"id":"2972","name":"MBC 1","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TR/mbc1-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC1En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc1.png"},{"id":"1858","name":"MBC 2","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc2-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC2En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc2.png"},{"id":"1859","name":"MBC 3","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc3-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc3.png"}]
```

I want to get the value of link count.

Can anyone help?

I tried to do:

```
    <?php
    $content =     file_get_contents("https://android.rediptv2.com/ch.php?usercode=5266113827&pid=1&mac=02:00:00:00:00:00&sn=&customer=GOOGLE&lang=eng&cs=amlogic&check=3177926680");

$result  = json_decode($content);

print_r( $result->link );
?>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Why is this tagged as JavaScript?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What _did_ it do?

Comment: Calling that URL directly in my browser, only gives me the response `[{"Message":"Connection Failed"}]` - do you have any reason to believe that this will behave differently, inside your script?

Comment: When you want to debug things, do a `var_export($result)` or `print_r($result)` before trying to access a property of the variable. Typically, in your case, the variable was an array and you accessed a missing property so it generated an error. I gave you the full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the JSON in an editor and **you'll see that it's an array and not an object with the `link` attribute**. This is why you cannot access it directly. You have to loop over the items and then you'll be able to access the `link` property of one of the items. If you need to access the link by id, as you asked 4 months later, then just create a dictionnary in an array indexed by id and containing just the interesting data you need.

PHP code:

```php
<?php

// The result of the request:
$content = <<<END_OF_STRING
[{"id":"2972","name":"MBC 1","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TR/mbc1-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC1En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc1.png"},{"id":"1858","name":"MBC 2","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc2-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/MBC2En.ae-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc2.png"},{"id":"1859","name":"MBC 3","link":"http://46.105.112.116/?watch=TN/mbc3-ar&token=RED_cexVeBNZ8mioQnjmGiYNEg==,1643770076.5266113827&t=1&s=2&p=1&c=BR&r=1351&lb=1","epg":"https://epg.cdnrdn.com/-20220201.xml","dvr":"disabled","language":"Arabic","category":"TOP 100","logo":"http://files.rednetcontent.com/chlogo/mbc3.png"}]
END_OF_STRING;

$items = json_decode($content);

echo '$items = ' . var_export($items, true) . "\n\n";

// Create a dictionnary to store each link accessible by id.
$links_by_id = [];

// Loop over all items:
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    // Show how to access the current link.
    echo "Link $i = $item->link\n";
    
    // Fill the dictionary.
    $links_by_id[(int)$item->id] = $item->link;
}

// To access the first one:
echo "\nFirst link = " . $items[0]->link . "\n";

// Example of access by id:
// The id seems to be a string. It could probably be "1895" or "zhb34" or whatever.
// (If they are only numbers, we could convert the string to an integer).
$id = "1859";
echo "\nAccess with id $id = " . $links_by_id[$id] . "\n";
```

Test it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/e8ab9

Another important point: **You are getting a 403 Forbidden error** on the URL you provided. So typically, you will not obtain the JSON you wanted.

As I explained in the comment below, I think that you will not be able to access this page without having a fresh URL with valid query parameters and/or cookies. I imagine you obtained this URL from somewhere and it is no longer valid. This is why **you'll probably need to use *cURL* to visit the website with a session to obtain the fresh URL to the JSON API**. Use Google to find some examples of PHP scraping/crawling with session handling. You'll see that depending on the website it can get rather tricky, especially if some JavaScript comes into the game.

Comment: But when i add url

Comment: https://android.rediptv2.com/ch.php?usercode=5266113827&pid=1&mac=02:00:00:00:00:00&sn=&customer=GOOGLE&lang=eng&cs=amlogic&check=3177926680
I get this message

Warning: file_get_contents(https://android.rediptv2.com/ch.php?usercode=5266113827&pid=1&mac=02:00:00:00:00:00&sn=&customer=GOOGLE&lang=eng&cs=amlogic&check=3177926680): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN in /home/vtpioino/public_html/ch.php on line 6
$items = NULL
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vtpioino/public_html/ch.php on line 17
First link =

Comment: <?php

$api_url = 'https://android.rediptv2.com/ch.php?usercode=5266113827&pid=1&mac=02:00:00:00:00:00&sn=&customer=GOOGLE&lang=eng&cs=amlogic&check=3177926680';

// Read JSON file
$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);

// Decode JSON data into PHP array



$items = json_decode($json_data);

echo '$items = ' . var_export($items, true) . "\n\n";

// Loop over all items:
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    echo "Link $i = $item->link\n";
}

// To access the first one:
echo "\nFirst link = " . $items[0]->link . "\n";

Comment: @achraf The error message is clear: you are getting a 403 error, meaning that you are not allowed to access this URL, it's as simple as that! But when I look at the query string I see a `usercode` and a `check` parameter that let's me think that you need to have a session first. [You'll have to use cURL with a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424714/how-to-maintain-session-in-curl-in-php). First authentify to get the access to the web site and then get the correct URL to what you want to scrap and then get it with the same session cookie.

Comment: @achraf If you need to learn **how to use cURL** then Google a bit or [view a video on Youtube about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQqR-gKBBz0).

Comment: How i can get link via id?

Comment: How i can get link via id?

Comment: @achraf: I updated the answer by adding a dictionnary to save the links by ids.